# Using a UIHint annotation on a list of complex objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use a UIHint for each complex element in an list that is included in my view model. I can currently use`@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.ContentElements[0], "MYContent")` but would like to move the hint to the actual view model instead of in the Html.DisplayFor helper. Is this possible with the view models structured as they are?

My view model:

```
 public class MyViewModel
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public IList<ContentElement> ContentElements { get; set; }
}
```

My complex element:

```
 public class ContentElement 
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

MYContent template:

```
@model  ContentElement
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled){

<span>@Model.ContentId</span>
}
@Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. You do not need a `[UIHint]` attribute. If your `DisplayTemplate` is named `ContentElement.cshtml` and located in the `/Vews/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder, then all you need in the main view is `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContentElements)`

Comment: I did not know that. Would mark as an answer if I could. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `[UIHint]` in this case (and if you did, you would need to change the template to use `@model List<ContentElement>`). All that is necessary is that you name your template `ContentElement.cshtml` (to match the name of the class) and place it in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` (or `/Views/{ControllerName}/DisplayTemplates`) folder, and then in the view use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ContentElements)
```

If however you did want to use `[UIHint]`, then you would apply it to the `ContentElements` property

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    [UIHint("MYContent")]
    public IList<ContentElement> ContentElements { get; set; }
}
```

but because `ContentElements` is `List<ContentElement>`, then it means the the model in the template must be `@model List<ContentElement>` (not `@model ContentElement`)